# R- represent glmm (Package MuMin and lme4) with categorical and numeric variable

Tags: r, plot, lme4

I have a table with Ancylostoma's infection, vs sex (2 factor), location (2 factor), year, management (2 factor), ancestry (4 factor) and  viremia like categorical variable, and the I have HL an age like numeric variable.**

I made a glmm:

```
glm_toxo<-glmer((Ancylostoma) ~ as.factor(Sexo)+(Edad)+as.factor(año)+as.factor(Manejo)+as.factor(Localizacion)+as.factor(Viremia.FeLV) +(Ancestria) +(HL)+as.factor(1|Nombre), family="binomial", data= data_silv)

dd_toxo <- dredge (glm_toxo)
a<- get.models(dd_toxo, subset = delta < 2)
b<-(model.avg(a))
```

And I got this result

```
Model-averaged coefficients: 
                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                   -2.0222     0.8911   2.269   0.0233 *  
as.factor(Localizacion)PORT  -15.2935  2163.9182   0.007   0.9944    
as.factor(Localizacion)SMO    -3.0012     0.7606   3.946 7.95e-05 ***
as.factor(Manejo)SILV          1.8125     0.7799   2.324   0.0201 *  
Edad                          -0.1965     0.1032   1.904   0.0569 .  
as.factor(Sexo)M               0.5015     0.4681   1.071   0.2840    
HL                            -0.9381     1.4244   0.659   0.5102    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I would like represent the probability of infection (y) vs age (x), but using the estimate of my model.avg**

I tried with this script:

```
nseq <- function(x, len = length(x)) seq(min(x, na.rm = TRUE),max(x, na.rm=TRUE), length = len)

####
newdata <- as.data.frame(lapply(lapply(data_silv[2:4], mean), rep, 213))
newdata$Edad <- nseq(data_silv$Edad, nrow(newdata))
(año <- sample(as.factor(data_silv$año),size=213,rep=T))
(Manejo <- sample(as.factor(data_silv$Manejo),size=213,rep=T))
(Sexo <- sample(as.factor(data_silv$Sexo),size=213,rep=T))
newdata <- as.data.frame(cbind(mean(data_silv$HL), año,Manejo,Sexo,
                 data_silv$Localizacion, nseq(data_silv$Edad, nrow(newdata)),
                 data_silv$Ancylostoma))
names(newdata) <- c("HL","año","Manejo","Sexo","Localizacion","Edad",
"Ancylostoma")


newdata$pred <- data.frame(
  model = sapply(a, predict, newdata = newdata),
  averaged.subset = predict(b, newdata, full = FALSE),
  averaged.full = predict(b, newdata, full = TRUE)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(newdata,aes(x="Edad",y="pred",color="Localizacion")) + geom_line()
#####
```

But I haven't got graph...or I have error

Someone know any form to represent my model.avg with categorical and variable numeric?, But taking into account that I only want represent  probability of infection vs age, with two line: localizacion1 and localizacion2...(localization had 2 factors).**

my original date would be this table:

### #

```
año <- sample(as.factor(2005:2009),size=213,rep=T)
riqueza <- sample((0:3),size=213,rep=T)
HL <- rnorm(213, mean=0.54, sd=0.13)

Ancylostoma <- sample(as.factor(0:1),size=213,rep=T)

Edad <- sample(as.factor(0:21),size=213,rep=T)
Manejo<- sample(c("CCC", "SILV"), 213, replace = TRUE)
Sexo<- sample(c("M", "H"), 213, replace = TRUE)
Localizacion<- sample(c("SMO", "DON", "PORT"), 213, replace = TRUE)
Ancestria<- sample(c("DON", "SMO", "F1", "F2"), 213, replace = TRUE)

newdata <- as.data.frame(cbind(HL,año,Manejo,Sexo,
                               Localizacion, Edad,Ancylostoma))


names(newdata) <- c("HL","año","Manejo","Sexo","Localizacion","Edad",
                    "Ancylostoma")
```

### #

And with that date I make my model's estimates. Then I would like do prediction

Thank you, I don't sure if I am explaining well

I so sorry for my english

Comment: If you can make a reproducible example (see http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ) I would be willing to take a crack at this.  You will either need to post your data set somewhere, or find a data set that is appropriately complex (e.g. two categorical input variables, one of which needs to be averaged over and the other represented by multiple lines in the graph, and one continuous input variable).

Comment: I don't sure if I am explaining well...I have my estimates average of my model, and the I would like represent it, so I would like do prediction

Comment: the point of a reproducible example is that it makes it much easier to explain what you're aiming for, and for people to experiment.  Did you read the link?

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't sure how should be the example, and wheter I had made was well.I added the example to my question